# In MacOS (Sierra) where are the mail rules stored?

Tags: macos, apple-mail

I rely on mail rules to implement a white-list function and since I am busy I have quite a few rules.   The dialog box (in Mail Preferences) is inadequate for the task.

So what I want to do is export the rules to some text format, edit them externally (maybe in Python or just a text editor) and then re-import them.

The problem is I cannot find the file where the Mail program stores these rules.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of macOS Sierra, Mail rules are stored in `~/Library/Mail/V4/MailData/SyncedRules.plist`.

High Sierra: `~/Library/Mail/V5/MailData/SyncedRules.plist`

Mojave: `~/Library/Mail/V6/MailData/SyncedRules.plist`

Comment: Thanks -- I wonder why I couldn't find it before.  I tried "find . | grep -i rules" and it never found any files.  But it looks like the data structure is pretty intuitive so I think I can do what I want.